# How to get minimum fare between two cities

Tags: c#, sql-server, algorithm, data-structures, shortest-path

I have below table

```
Source  Destination   Fare
A         B            10
B         C            5
B         D            1
D         C            1
A         D            1
```

Now I wanted to write a query which will give me the minimum fare between two cities.

For example if I want to go A->C then minimum fare is 2 A->D->C

What will be MS-Sql query for this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that you will be able to get information via single sql query

Comment: You need a [**Travelling salesman problem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) algorithm

Comment: Actually you need a single-source shortest path algorithm such as Dijkstra's algorithm. You would use the fares as the edge values. The TSP won't work since it would give you the minimum cost route to visit ALL cities, not just the two that you are interested in.

Comment: http://hansolav.net/blog/ImplementingDijkstrasAlgorithmUsingTSQL.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
;WITH Paths AS (
   -- Anchor query: get first step
   SELECT CAST(CONCAT(Source, '->', Destination) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Path, 
          Destination, Fare, 
          IIF(Destination = 'C', 1, 0) AS Terminate
   FROM mytable
   WHERE Source = 'A'

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive part: get next step
   SELECT CAST(CONCAT(Path, '->', t.Destination) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Path, 
          t.Destination, Fare = t.Fare + p.Fare, 
          IIF(t.Destination = 'C', 1, 0) AS Terminate
   FROM mytable AS t
   JOIN Paths AS p ON t.Source = p.Destination
   WHERE p.Destination <> 'C'
)
SELECT Path, Fare
FROM (
  SELECT Path, Fare,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Fare) AS rnk
  FROM Paths
  WHERE Terminate = 1) AS t
WHERE t.rnk = 1
```

This is sort of a brute force method: it uses a *recursive CTE* to get all possible paths. Then using `RANK` we can select the one(s) having the minimum fare.

[**Demo here**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/490079)

Comment: This is a very good answer but should you not also check for you terminate condition on your anchor query? If source is A and destination B then the current query will not return a result.

Comment: @EdmondQuinton This will be caught by the *first* execution of the recursive part: `...WHERE p.Destination <> 'C'`

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. In your final select clause, you are only returning rows for which it is determined that the path had terminated at the destination (WHERE Terminate = 1). However, if the current query is modified to search for minimum fare from A to B then the only path available would be the direct path of A->B with a fare of 10. However, since the anchor query always gives 0 as the Terminate condition and the path A->B won’t be included in the recursive path of the query then no result will be returned.

Comment: @EdmondQuinton Yes, you are correct. Very good explanation, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No worries, awesome answer :)

Answer (score -4):

have you try to google:
sql server travelling salesman
or 
sql server shortest path

There are tons of answers

Comment: this info should fit in the comment section nicely

Comment: Not really an answer

Comment: this is not an answer

Comment: Actually it was an answer, guys. Because it brings him to find out the best way to solve his problem. But what did you do here actually? ... Well... I help you with the answer: NOTHING! Beside the fact you have shouting over me "It's not an answer, it's not an answer!" Why would I copy here the solutions which already exists over the net if he can do this by himself??? Did you suggest at least the same? Well... no. So this IS the answer

Comment: *USE GOOGLE* isnt really an answer, is just a comment. That is what we are trying to tell you. For example I include a comment with a link to TSP wikipedia. Giorgos Betsos write a nice algorithm. See the difference?

Comment: Yeah, but here you have limited your answer to one particular solution wheras mine (with the required keywords specified) was opening the door for a lot of different approaches, the theory behind etc. Sometime I also miss the right keywords when I try to find again something I've seen in the past, but I didn't remember how I've found it